# Whats the smallest set of functions that I have to override, if I want to capture all uses of arrays in my javascript app?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm experimenting with writing some logging/tracking tools to use with my javascript applications, and i'm curious if I can track absolutely all times i access/use arrays within my application

towards this end, I'm wondering:

what is the absolutely smallest set of properties that i have to override on the array implementation, such that any attempts to access an array will go through calls to my logging/tracking functions?

Comment: The smallest amount to capture any attempt? Everything.

Comment: i think they fixed the instance-hijacking constructor-overloading techniques you want in the name of security.